# R-Studio csv import separated by commas, but containing semicolons in some strings

Tags: r, csv, csv-import

I am trying to import a csv file into R-Studio. The columns are separated by a comma, but the problem is that one column contains a String and this String sometimes is only formed by chars, sometimes it contains a semicolon (like "abcdefg33;asbfsk2ala;shcjd22l"). In any case this string should not be separated, the semicolons are not separators.

What happens is that for these lines where this column contains semicolons, nothing is separated.
The other lines instead work well.

The result looks like this:

```
Column1                                Column2   Column3
a                                      12        abc12 
b                                      222       bbbb222
c,333,abcdefg33;asbfsk2ala;shcjd22l
d                                      282       ddbb232
```

To import the data I tryed using this code, but in both case I get the result above.

```
data <- read.csv("Test.csv")
and
data <- read.csv("Test.csv", sep = ",", strip.white = TRUE)
```

Does anybody know how I can fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you copy a few rows of the csv that you are trying to read? If I try it replacing the whitespace in your example with commas, it reads just fine.

Comment: Year,Set,Week,Weekday,Code,Sum
2020,-,2020w15,Wednesday,UP1102306,123
2020,-,2020w15,Thursday,AWL883988;AWL243987;UHH890768,15
2020,-,2020w16,Wednesday,UP9102480,1
2020,-,2020w16,Thursday,UP0852487,30

Comment: The problem is that I periodically download this file and the goal is automation. Import, run, done.
I could of course every time open the file and replace the semicolon, but I hoped there is a solution maybe

Comment: i can't reproduce this; read.csv does not misread the given data (and I would not expect the semicolon to mess it up normally so this is intriguing). things to try: what is the smallest csv version that works, does removing semicolons actually fix the problem, are the line endings in the file right, is R updated...

Comment: I tryed removing some lines but nothing changed. Then I tryed removing all lines, leaving only the header line and one line containing the semicolons. The header is splitted (this does not contain semicolons) and the second line instead remains all together in the first column cell :/ i used: data <- read.csv("Test.csv", sep",")

Comment: Replacing semicolons with for example a minus, it works. But this is a change I have to do before in the csv file

Comment: The strane thing is that if I replace the semicolon with a comma, an error message shows up and the import doesn't work (more columns as columns names). This means the semicolon is not seen as a separator. But still nothing is split in these lines containing it

Answer (score 1):

I can simulate your result only if I explicitly add the double quotes in the csv file (e.g. with Notepad++):

```
a,12,1bc12
b,222,bbbb222
"c,333,abcdefg33;asbfsk2ala;shcjd22l"
d,282,ddbb232
```

In this case the resulting data frame looks like yours:

```
> data
                                   V1  V2      V3
1                                   a  12   1bc12
2                                   b 222 bbbb222
3 c,333,abcdefg33;asbfsk2ala;shcjd22l  NA        
4                                   d 282 ddbb232
```

My suggestion would be to ensure that your csv file does not contain the quotes.
Otherwise, you could use `readLines` to read the object line by line and then use e.g. regex to get rid of the quotes.

`fread` from `data.table` may help you:

```
library(data.table)
data4 <- fread("data_62871591.csv", sep = ",", quote = "")
```

Reads this file as follows:

```
> data4
   V1  V2                             V3
1:  a  12                          1bc12
2:  b 222                        bbbb222
3: "c 333 abcdefg33;asbfsk2ala;shcjd22l"
4:  d 282                        ddbb232
```

And as you can see there is still some post processing required to get rid of the quotes on row 3, columns V1 and V3.

Comment: Thank you, using test <- read.csv("Test1.csv", sep = ",", quote = "") I managed to split the data into columns. The only problem that remains is that column 1 now contains "c (c is right, but the quote sign should be removed). How can I remove it? I cannot use the substring function, because this happens not in every line, bot only in the lines where I have semicolons. If it can help you, c is a number, it's the year

Comment: Familiarise yourself with some basic regular expressions.